# His father [had washed] his face [when] he [got]

Tags: grammaticality

**Sentence:**

The little boy was one of those kids who hate water, but now thanks to his father he was clean. His father **had washed** his face **when** he **got** himself in a big mess with jam and butter.

**Question:**

Have I used "had washed", "when" and "got" correctly in the above sentence? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other than the slightly ambiguous use of "his" and "he" there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It would make more sense if the father washed the boy's face after the mess. Here, he washed the boy before the mess. Either the father *washed* his face (not had washed), or he had washed his face *before* he got into the mess (not when).

Comment: I don't quite understand. What tells us that he washed the boy's face before the mess?